# Manipulate php array?

Tags: php

I have one array link

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 16
    [11] => 17
    [12] => 18
    [13] => 19
    [14] => 20
    [15] => 21
    [16] => 22
    [17] => 23
    [18] => 24
    [19] => 25
    [20] => 26
    [21] => 27
    [22] => 28
    [23] => 29
    [24] => 30
)
```

but i want to make it in single array so after i can search for a value from a single array !

as like  ->

```
array("1","2","3")
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You have one array in input what is the problem to search in it ?

Comment: That is what your array looks like. Do you want the key to match the value?

Comment: Make your Question clear

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
"There is no issue" or is extremely unclear.

Comment: i think you are confused in array because the thing you want is same as your result so i think you need to study about array first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is fine. When not defining a `key` yourself, PHP adds keys from `0` and upwards.

When you want to check if a value is present in the array use `in_array()`.

Example:

```
$numbers = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
if (in_array("1", $numbers)) {
    echo "1 is in numbers";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `array_values()`, but in your specific case you won't need it. Your array already uses the default keys (0,1,2,...) which are as well used if you don't define them.

```
$arr1 = Array ( 
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 5
);
$arr2 = Array (1,3,5);
```

Both arrays produce the same output:

`var_dump($arr1)` = `array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(5) }`
`var_dump($arr2)` = `array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(5) }`
and surprise:
`var_dump(array_values($arr1))` = `array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(5) }`

If you define keys you can use `array_values()` properly:

```
$arr3 = Array ( 
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 3,
    "three" => 5
);
```

`var_dump($arr3)` = `array(3) { ["one"]=> int(1) ["two"]=> int(3) ["three"]=> int(5) }`
`var_dump(array_values($arr3))` = `array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(5) }`